# HIPAA compliant BI reporting tool?

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, report, tableau-api, business-intelligence

We are building an application for healthcare industry and we are planning to use a 3rd party BI tool for reporting which will directly connect to our postgres DB and generate the desired reports which we should be able to download as CSV or PDF. Reports will contain PHI data like list of patient in a particular zip (this is a simple example, complex scenarios will be there and even complete adhoc reporting can be there as well)

But as per requirement of HIPAA we should be able to log who access the PHI data and what was accessed. I reviewed some of the tools like Tableau. It manages audit log in files and keep record of the user and the underlying sql query which was made to the DB but not the records which were fetched as result of that query. So how can we accomplish this?

One approach we thought if we find some postgres extension which can log all the queries ran on the DB along with results but unable to find such plugin as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try extensions/plugins offered by Tableau or Jasper? If they have any extension which makes the reporting tool HIPAA compliant?

Comment: I looked for few but couldn't find any which could satisfy our exact needs.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to create a function that logs the select (in the database) and then use that as a data source on any analytics platform.

There will be performance implications, it would have to be tested.

I'm not a prostgresql expert, but this should help you get started:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html

Another way is to read the Tableau log and then determine the results of the sql query seperately:
https://community.tableau.com/thread/201817

I would get the query that has PHI and then run it against SQL and log what records are returned.  You could run it often so the records shouldn't change much.